# LINQ filter with or

Tags: c#, linq

I got the following structure:

```
 One user can have many Groups and a Group can have many users.
```

Now I want to get all users that are in the same group like the user to filter by.

For example,
The user "Theo" is in Group one and two. I want all users that are in Group one OR Group two.

How can I achive this with LINQ or generally c#?

This code doesn't work:

```
var res = (IEnumerable<User>)Users;
foreach (var item in user.Groups) {
    res = res.Where(usr => usr.Groups.Contains(item));
}
return res.ToList();
```

`Users` is a list I got from another method and `user` is a parameter of type `User`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume:

- The `User` class has a property `Groups` of type `List<Group>`
- The `Group` class has a property `Users` of type `List<User>`

Use the LINQ `SelectMany` method:

```
var usersInSameGroups = user.Groups.SelectMany(group => group.Users).ToList();
```

Or in query-syntax:

```
var usersInSameGroups = (from g in user.Groups
                         from userInGroup in g.Users
                         select userInGroup).ToList();
```

#### UPDATE

```
return (from user2 in Users
        where user2.Groups.Intersect(user.Groups).Any()  // Keeps only user2 if it has a common group with user
        select user2).ToList();
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've always called "pure LINQ" the second one. Thanks for this correction.

Comment: Where should I write it? In the loop or as replacement for the loop?

Comment: Ok, but I the list I got from the other method is filtered.

Comment: @Knerd I've updated my post, because I think my second assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using `Intersect.Any` on the groups:

```
var groupsFind = new []{"Group1","Group2"};
var userFound = allUsers
    .Where(u => u.Groups
                 .Select(ug => ug.Name)
                 .Intersect(groupsFind)
                 .Any());
```

I don't understand the model, a user belongs to n groups and every group can have n users. Isn't the last relation redundant or the same as the first just vice-versa?

Comment: Here is a DB diagram of the model: http://sdrv.ms/UP5BaD

The Group is connected to many other entities.

Comment: @Knerd: Ok, then one user can belong to n-groups. Then above works, at least with Linq-To-Objects. I'm not familiar with LinqTo-EF and you should tag that next time.

Comment: Yes thanks, I will tag it next time right. The solution of Cédric Bignon worked great :)